# How do i move magento store to another domain?

Tags: magento, migrating

I have my magento store on a subdomain, and now I chose the final domain I want the website to be on, but I don't know how to move it, what do I need to change?

I tried changing the base_url in the SQl files but it doesnt seem to do the trick.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you migrate the files and database to your new domain, after that go to your database and run the SQL modifying the desired URL below:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://urlteste.com.br/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; 

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://urlteste.com.br/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

TRUNCATE also makes the following tables: 
log_url 
log_url_info 
log_visitor 
log_visitor_info

After that clean the cache of your Magento which is in var/cache/* folder and test again.